# Sprite kit - how to display half of sprite/texture/image

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am working on a Sprite Kit project in which I need to display in some cases only half of an existing image.

I tried making the frame of the sprite smaller, but it just stretches the image.

Is there any possibility to use a mask or something in order to display only half of the sprite/image/texture?

Comment: yes it is possible. You can do it with [centerRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/centerRect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, in order to show only half of the image, texture, sprite, someone would need to use a SKCropNode. The only sensible thing is to crop the sprite you need starting from half, not just cropping with a predefined size. This can be achieved by setting the mask node position.

1) create a SkSpriteNode with that texture/image:

```
// Obj-C
SKSpriteNode *skelet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];

// Swift
let skelet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
```

2) create the SKCropNode:

```
// Obj-C
SKCropNode * cropNode = [SKCropNode node];

// Swift
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
```

3) create the mask

```
// Obj-C
SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(skelet.frame.size.width/2, skelet.frame.size.height)];

// Swift
let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: skelet.frame.size.width/2, height: skelet.frame.size.height))
```

** set the mask position to the half of the result you need (you need half of the skelet -> set the mask position to the half "of the half of the skelet")

```
// Obj-C
mask.position = CGPointMake(skelet.frame.size.width/4, 0);

// Swift
mask.position = CGPoint(x: skelet.frame.size.width/4, y: 0)
```

The division by 4 is because you need the center of the mask to be not in the center of the skelet node, but moved to the half of a half of the skelet (reminder the mask node works with a default anchor point of 0.5 0.5 - so the zero point corresponds with the center of the skelet node).

4) add the needed elements to the crop node

```
// Obj-C
[cropNode addChild:skelet];
[cropNode setMaskNode:mask];
[self addChild:cropNode];

// Swift
cropNode.addChild(skelet)
cropNode.maskNode = mask
self.addChild(cropNode)
```